# How can I convert an ExpandoObject to Dictionary in C#?

Tags: javascript, c#, dictionary, expandoobject

I'm using Jint to execute JavaScript in a Xamarin app. Jint is converting an associative array into an ExpandoObject. How do I use this object? Ideally, I'd like to get a dictionary of the data out of it.

JavaScript returns:

```
return {blah:abc, bleh:xyz};
```

Debugger of Object that Jint returns looks like:

[image]

Comment: @bzlm:  Not a dupe.  This is specific how-to question about creating a dictionary from `ExpandoObject`.

Comment: The only way to do it I've found is: `((IDictionary<string, object>)result).ToDictionary(nvp => nvp.Key, nvp => nvp.Value)`

Answer (score 34, accepted):

It already IS a dictionary. Just implicitly cast it:

```
IDictionary<string, object> dictionary_object = expando_object;
```

And then use it like one. BTW: this is also the reason why [recursive's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32618425/how-can-i-convert-an-expandoobject-to-dictionary-in-c/32618465#32618465) works.

Comment: This doesn't change the json behavior. It still serializes as `[{"Key":"Property1Name", "Value":"Property1Value"}, {"Key":"Property2Name", "Value":"Property2Value"}]`

Answer (score 18):

Just pass it to the constructor.

```
var dictionary = new Dictionary<string, object>(result);
```

Comment: If `result` is `object`, which on `expando` I believe it is, then this won't compile. It will find the constructor that takes an `int` instead.

Comment: Everything is an object.  But result is dynamically typed and the concrete type implements IDictionary.  Try it and you'll see.

Comment: I did. It won't compile like that. I have a list of expando objects and `Json(results.Data.Select(o => new Dictionary<string, object>(o))` won't compile. I get error: "CS1503 Argument 1: cannot convert from 'object' to 'int'". Hovering over `o` tells me that parameter `o` is `object`. So, `results.Data.Select(o => ((IDictionary<string, object>)o).ToDictionary(nvp => nvp.Key, nvp => nvp.Value))` is the only way I could get it to work.

Comment: The dictionary constructor takes an `IDictionary`, which `ExpandoObject` is.  However if the static declaration of your variable is `object`, the compiler can't verify it.  `ExpandoObject` instances are usually declared dynamic.  That would work.  In your example, you cast `o` to `(IDictionary<string, object>)`.